# How did the dog do it?

Tags: knowledge, situation

> A man stands on one side of a river, his dog on the other. The man
> calls his dog, who immediately crosses the river without getting wet
> and without using a bridge or a boat.

How did the dog do it? (There are many answers to this question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be that the river is frozen? Because then the dog would not get wet and could walk across easily if the river is thick enough.

Comment: That's the answer, congratulations!

Answer (score 3):

The river is seasonal and currently dry. Or the dog is on the other side of a sharp bend in the river and can just walk around. Or the river is narrow and the dog can jump over. Or the river is underground. Or the dog is wearing waders.

Comment: This is a reasonable answer, but the real answer is not this one. Even so, I upvoted.

Comment: No, these are *all* “the real answer”. They just aren’t the same as the answer you came up with.

Comment: So, should I post the answer I came up with?

Comment: If you like, though it would be unusual to post it so soon after posting the original question. After all, other people might also want to try to answer.

Comment: Also, why are there so many downvotes?

Comment: @MyCar The downvotes (not me) will likely be because there are so many possible correct answers to this question (as shown by this answer). This site lends itself best to questions where there is a single provably-correct answer, so riddles like this don't necessarily 'do very well' here. See [this meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1254/why-are-questions-off-topic-if-they-invite-answers-which-are-not-demonstrably-co) for more information...

Comment: @Stiv I edited.

Comment: @MyCar No need to spam the comments section with suggestions of your other posts. Most of us regulars check the front page pretty regularly and will see other recently posted puzzles when we come online...